# Wierd behaviour for UIButton setHighlighted after the button is set selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, selected, ibaction

My question is simple: I am creating a UIButton with resources for normal, disabled, selected and highlighted, in other words, all the controls I have access to. The problem is that, if for some reason I choose to set the button to be selected, and afterwards I tap on it, none of the resources I've set is shown.

`setSelected = YES`  Correct resource
`setHightlighted = YES` Correct resource
`setNormal = YES` Correct resource
etc.

I've verified all the resources and everything is in order. I'm not changing the state of the button in an `IBAction`, so that is not the case here.

Again, the weird appearance happens when the button is selected and I tap on it (like a highlight version of the selected state - if that makes any sense). How do I have access to this part? Or what do I have to do for this not to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part cannot be set in the xib file, but you have access to it by giving him a resource for the (Highlighted|Selected) state in the code.

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
```

It's also a duplicate of : [UIButton: set image for selected-highlighted state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592646/uibutton-set-image-for-selected-highlighted-state)

Comment: That's correct, thank you. I need to wait 8 more minutes, before I can approve