# UIButton Highlighted image not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, xcode7

I have a `UIButton`(Button place at bottom) setting the properties via `storyboard`. While tap on the button not showing the `Highlighted` image of the button but, button Click is working, Other buttons in the screen showing the  Highlighted image.
**Edit:**
The button is place on bottom of the screen,
My screen size is 320x568, - I have placed three buttons with Y value 515, that is not working. (button width- 75, height - 37)
Also tried to change the button position then, it is working fine.

I am using Xcode 7.1.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592646/uibutton-set-image-for-selected-highlighted-state

Comment: @vaibby: not working

Comment: @vaibby: I have issue with the bottom button only. I changed the button position to top then, it is working fine.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of which button is not working and which is working?\

Comment: @FahimParkar : My screen size is 320x568, - I have placed three buttons with Y value 515, that is not working. (button width- 75, height - 37).

Comment: do you have any view as subview and you are putting those buttons inside those subview?

Comment: are you able to click those buttons or on click event is also not getting called?

Comment: @FahimParkar: I can click and Event is called, working fine but highlighted image not displaying when touch at edges of the button.

Comment: okay, as you are saying your screen size is 320x568.. so are you testing on iPhone 4s or 5s and more?

Comment: did you copy-paste that button on storyboard ? if yes then drag and drop a button and then set values. and when you set values make sure button state is highlighted

Comment: @VineeshTP put your code.

Comment: @BhaveshNai:  
I have set the property in storyboard itself.

Comment: @VineeshTP use autolayout ?

Comment: @BhaveshNai: I can get the button click , but highlighted image not showing.

Comment: @VineeshTP set image as selected mode and chack again. image change or not

Comment: The issue is while tap on edge of the button(button action is working). Other wise it is working fine.

Comment: @VineeshTP check my code

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.It will help you.

```
[Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: I have set the property in storyboard itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)YourButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Comment: you can try programatically create button and check it. not storyboard.

Comment: I have tried the same programatically. Also tried to change the button position then, it is working fine

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, link?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with similar issue. What I did is setting appropriate image for each state

```
-(void)setupMediaPlusButtonImagesForStates {

    [self.mediaPlusButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"details_plus_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.mediaPlusButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"details_plus_highlighted_icon"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted)];    

    [self.mediaPlusButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];    

    [self.mediaPlusButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_button_highlighted.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected)];    
}
```