# Swift set button image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

When I try to change button's image when button pressed but it just shows a blue square as button's image

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
     buttonOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "thing"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
}
```

Comment: are you sure you changing the same button, and with correct image

Comment: yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Your_Image_Name"), for: .normal), this should always work, unless your button is in different state other than normal, or you have set image for different state

Comment: na photo and button is right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UIButton image in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837371/how-to-change-uibutton-image-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> A control becomes highlighted when a touch event enters the control’s
>   bounds...

[Highlighted state of a control](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state/1618220-highlighted)

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "button_normal_state"), for: .normal)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "button_pressed_state"), for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: this one was the first method that I tried and I tried it again and it worked I don't know how or why it failed at the first time but thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Just recheck that you have "thing" - image in your target.

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "thing"), for: [.selected, .highlighted])
```

And see this question
[UIButton: set image for selected-highlighted state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5592646/1678018)